# iOS game centre sandbox/live

Tags: ios, deployment, game-center

my iOS app I've been working on is working fine with game centre turn based play and leaderboards

*currently* its a development build and as such game center is logged into the testing game centre sandbox.

my question is around next step -

do i submit it to apple and from there it will get pointed to the live game centre

or should i test it against the live game centre first – if so – how?

is it sufficient to generate the ipa with an App Store distribution profile and that will get pointed to live game centre for further testing – or does it have to go through the app store submission process?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Live Game Center will be available for your app automatically when it is approved. 
You do not need to do anything for it.

But this process takes some time to propagate to all servers, so you can get a temporary warning "no Game Center for this game" or something like that. It will be gone in a few hours.

Comment: hi thanks for reply, so just to clarify, i don't need to do any explicit testing against the live game centre source prior to submission?

Comment: No, you don't. If it properly works  on sandbox, it will work on live too.